(Android Library module) How to access a parent project's ext.variable value in build.gradle?
it has been a long long while since I've been on stackoverflow. Been away from the tech space for a number of years working as a freelancer before returning to the workforce recently. I've just been handed an Android project in my new role and because of the terrible state of the code base, I have been tasked by my boss to clean it up and also to migrate the project into a clean, and upgraded project environment. Basically the android app that I am taking over is old, like 2016 old. I suspect that a lot of things are going to break when I am in the process of doing this migration.
First things first, I'm trying to migrate one of the Android Library modules to the clean environment. So I've just added a brand new library module to the clean android app (none of the existing project code has been added yet), and I see something within the old code and online docs about using/accessing the "ext" extra values from the parent/root project.
So,for example, in the parent project folder (build.gradle):
ext{
    compileSdkVersion = 24
}

In the Android Library module (build.gradle):
android {
    namespace 'com.stackoverflow.needhelp'
    compileSdk getRootProject().ext.minimumSdkVersion
} 


Is this the correct way to do it? Or must I add something else within the build.gradle file in the root folder?

You are doing it right, no worries
